# How to change the background color i.e. "element color and text color" of notification bar in Android...?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-styles, android-statusbar

I have to change the element color and text color of status bar and I also have to change the text color of title bar in Android:

The existing code is as follows:

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppThemeNew" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FDFEFE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#F4F6F6</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#088da5</color>
    <color name="status_bar_color">#F4F6F6</color>
    <color name="status_bar_element_color">#AAB7B8</color>
</resources>
```

row_data.xml

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX697.png)

Please help.....

Answer (score 1):

To change statusbar' element and text color, you could create custom theme like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

**Notes:**

1. `status_bar_color` would be your custom color resource.
2. `android:windowLightStatusBar` = true, status bar text color will be
   compatible (grey) when status bar color is light.

   `android:windowLightStatusBar` = false, status bar text color will
   be compatible (white) when status bar color is dark.

   [ref is here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowLightStatusBar)
3. Tested in above api level 23

Comment: Even after setting android:windowLightStatusBar = true, I am not able to get the status bar elements as **gray** , I think `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>` won't work at all, as it by default takes @color/colorPrimaryDark as its status bar color. The code is as follows: `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> `

Answer (score 0):

The action bar takes the colour for the titles and icons from `textColorPrimary`

However this will also affect the default text for edit texts and text views if you set it on the app theme.

To get around this create a separate theme for the app bar that includes the text colour change and either reference it in the app theme as the app bar style or set it on the toolbar in the XML if you have a custom toolbar.

Comment: Toolbar title color changes as per your suggestion, but still I couldn't change the notification bar's element color.